# pandoc: Undefined control sequence ... unless I include some ```code```

Tags: pandoc, markdown

this markdown document:

```
---
author: Benoît
toc: true
papersize: a4
pagenumbering: true
---

# test

Hello.

\textcolor{green}{green}
```

makes `pandoc --from=markdown foo.md -o foo.pdf` fail and output:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.70 \textcolor
```

However, if I include at the end of the document a simple:

````
```sh
hello
```
````

then pandoc is happy.

What's going on here ?

Comment: Which version of pandoc are you using? With pandoc 2.9.1.1 there are no errors.

Comment: pandoc 2.5
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.5.4, texmath 0.11.2.2, skylighting 0.7.7

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i think that xcolors is only included when some features are used, like code verbatim.

Adding this in header solves the problem:

```
header-includes: |
        \usepackage{xcolor}
```